# Form calculating insurance for motorbikes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am making a form for my college. It is supposed to calculate the insurance for motorbikes based on the size of the engine, extras (such as windscreen coverage, content coverage and breakdown coverage) and the form of insurance(fully comp, third party) and theft.

However for some reason it is not calculating it properly. When I tick windscreen and content, it is adding the 5 and the 25. However when I tick all three it is supposed to add 85 in total. Because screen adds 5 and content coverage adds 25 and breakdown coverage adds 50. So it should all add up, but for some reason it does not.

And when I change the inscover which is supposed to be used to calculate the insurance based on the level of coverage (comp, third party etc.)

I will be attaching the code, if someone could take a look at it please?

```js
var excover = 0; //excover holds excess cover set by checkboxes
var standard = 50; //standard is set to an insurance base cost
var engsize = 0;
var inscover = 25;

cover = new Array(3)
cover[0] = 45
cover[1] = 65
cover[2] = 110

function boxcheck() {
  excover = 0;
  if (document.form1.screen.checked)
    excover = excover + 5
  if (document.form1.content.checked)
    excover = excover + 25
  if (document.form1.breakdown.checked)
    excover = excover + 50

  //Find radio buttons checked
  for (loop = 0; loop < document.form1.engine.length; loop++)
    if (document.form1.engine[loop].checked)
      engsize = loop + 1
  //Find insurance cover
  inscover = document.form1.covertype.selectedIndex
  document.form1.quote.value = (standard * engsize) + excover +
    cover[inscover]
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">A demonstration form</h1>
<br>
<hr><br>
<form method="post" action="address" name="form1">
  <h2>Please enter the following details</h2>
  <br> The make of your motorbike:
  <INPUT TYPE=text NAME=make onBlur="if (this.value == '') {alert('Please enter the make of your motorbike'); return false;  this.focus()}">
  <br><br> The model: <input type=text name=model>
  <br><br> Your address:
  <br>
  <textarea name=address rows=4 cols=50></textarea>
  <br>
  <h3> Please select your extended cover options</h3>
  <input type="checkbox" name="screen" value="windscreen">Windscreen
  <input type="checkbox" name="content" value="contents">Contents
  <input type="checkbox" name="breakdown" value="recovery">Breakdown Recovery
  <br>
  <br>
  <H3>Please click-on the engine capacity range of your vehicle</H3>
  <BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="engine" VALUE="small" CHECKED> under 500 cc
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="engine" VALUE="medium"> 500 - 1000 cc
  <INPUT TYPE="radio" NAME="engine" VALUE="large"> over 1000 cc
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR> Please select insurance cover:&nbsp;
  <SELECT NAME="covertype" SIZE=1>
    <OPTION SELECTED>Third party
      <OPTION>Third party fire and theft
        <OPTION>Comprehensive
  </SELECT>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Get quote" VALUE="See Quote" onClick="boxcheck()">
  <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="quote">
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <BR>
  <input type=button value="Submit Details">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear the entry">
</form>
```

Comment: Please close the option tags - I know you do not HAVE to, but it looks nicer when prettyprinting

Comment: _"However when I tick all three it is supposed to add 85 in total. Because screen adds 5 and content coverage adds 25 and breakdown coverage adds 50."_ - that's 80, not 85. And your script does calculate _that_ part correctly, which you can easily verify if you do a `console.log(excover)` after those first three ifs.

Comment: Will do it now.

Comment: CBroe. that is true. Sorry I don't know why i missed that. But the inscover still doesn't work correctly for some reason. It is supposed to calculate the insurance based on the coverage type(comp third party etc.)

Comment: When I log `inscover` and `cover[inscover]`, those both show the expected values as well. You need to properly explain _what_ is supposed to be wrong with the result.